# How to create a DDOS protection for a webpage inside of the views

Tags: django, django-views, ddos

So recenty I have been working on a Django app for a school project, and some friends decided it would be funny to DDOS my webpage. I am currently looking for new friends and a way to protect against this. I am currently trying to use a decorator limits from the library. It does block when getting ddos attacked but the problem is it shuts down the whole website, giving the error RateLimitException, which i do not want, for obvious reasons. **I want the program to be able to block that specific ip address sending the requests, how could i do this**. Here is the imports in views with only the homepage.

```
import ratelimit
from ratelimit import limits
```

```
@limits(calls=5, period=10)
def home_page(request):
  request.session.get("user_id")
  if request.session.get('user_id') is not None:

    authorized=True
    return render(request,template_name="index.html",context={"authorize":authorized})
    
  else:
    return render(request,template_name="index.html")
```

. . . . . . . . . . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [django-ratelimit](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/). The `ratelimit` decorator allows you to block requests from [IP](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/keys.html#keys-chapter) if the number of requests is higher than `rate`.

```python
from django_ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit

@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='15/m', block=True)
def home_page(request):
    ...
```